# Does Android actually compare string using native code?

Tags: java, android, string, android-ndk

In the `String.java` for sdk-29, I saw that `compareTo()` is a native method, moreover, it is annotated with `@FastNative`. However, `equals()` is still implemented in Java.

Is that true that `compareTo()` is implemented using native code? If so, why isn't `equals()` implemented that way too? If not, then what is `@FastNative`?

Comment: _"what is @FastNative ?"_ https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/improvements